# sftp connection issues c#

Tags: c#, winforms, ssh, sftp

When I'm trying to connect to sftp Using Renci.SshNet I have this errors:

```
'client2.ProtocolVersion' threw an exception of type 'Renci.SshNet.Common.SshConnectionException'
'client2.WorkingDirectory' threw an exception of type 'Renci.SshNet.Common.SshConnectionException'
```

How I can fix it?

```
public void Upoad3(string filenames)
{
    try
    {
        const string host = "ftp";
        const string login = "login";
        const string pass = "pass";
        const string workingdirectory = "/w53850/";
        SftpClient client2 = new SftpClient(host, login, pass);
        client2.Connect();
        //client2.ChangeDirectory(workingdirectory);
        FileStream files = File.OpenRead(filenames);
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filenames, FileMode.Open))
        {
            client2.BufferSize = 4 * 1024;
            client2.UploadFile(fileStream, filenames);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it's not connecting to the sftp, possibly host unreachable or bad credentials. What does the exception message say? Does it have an inner exception?

Comment: What is the value of `ex.Message`? Exception type does not help much. - Actually the error, you have posted, does not look like it's from the code you have posted.

Comment: "A connection attempt failed host does not reply" something like this

Comment: @Ops, please execute again your code and add the `ex.Message`.